# Fallacy of the Devil You Know

Tags: epistemology, fallacies, reason, abduction, worldview

I just made up that name for the fallacy, but I'm wondering if there is a more common term for it. The fallacy is basically inferring from an inconclusive set of evidence to a particular explanation because that explanation happens to be a special interest of yours. For example,

> There is no way a comedian known for playing the piano with his male organ became president of Ukraine without some hidden influence; therefore, the CIA installed him in the presidency.

This is the sort of reasoning often used by conspiracy theorists. One species of conspiracy theorists are focused on the misdeeds of the CIA, so everything that happens that is hard to explain must have the CIA behind it. Others are focused on racism, so everything bad that happens is blamed on racism.

- Question 1: Is there a common name for this fallacy, and if so, what is it?
- Question 2: How does one distinguish this fallacy from inferring to the best explanation (called "abduction" by some authors)?

In both the fallacy of the devil you know and abduction, the best explanation is just the explanation you pick because given your background and interests, explanations of that sort happen to seem plausible to you. How can they be differentiated, if at all?

Comment: definitely seems more like a a cognitive bias than a fallacy, at least unless you include "i am inteersted in pianos" in your premises.

Comment: does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baconian_method#Idols_of_the_mind_(idola_mentis)) help? they are listed as inductive fallacies

Comment: I think he *pretended* to play the piano that way, not actually.

Comment: I don't think that is a good choice of name. The expression "the devil you know" is usually used when making a choice between options such that one is undesirable but has the merit of being familiar and tolerable, while other options involve more risk and could turn out worse. What you are describing seems to be a combination of conspiratorial thinking and false cause.

Comment: It is a case of [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias), "the tendency to search for, interpret, favor, and recall information in a way that confirms or supports one's prior beliefs or values". The [tunnel vision](https://www.populismstudies.org/Vocabulary/tunnel-vision/) metaphor is a colloquial equivalent, "tendency, habit, or conscious decision to only focus one’s energy or attention on a single particular thing or aspect, without regard for anything or anyone else." Some call it a fallacy.

Comment: @Conifold I think [motivated reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motivated_reasoning) is another term for what you are describing.

Comment: Can you say how 'Fallacy of the Devil You Know' is useful here, or might you just have well have chosen any name at random, as for instance 'Fallacy of the Telephone Book'?

Comment: How does your exposition support the idea that any explanation happens to be a special interest of anyone's?

Comment: What does 'inferring to the best explanation (called "abduction" by some authors)' mean?

Comment: Notice the example you used, OP, and the answer becomes obvious.

Comment: I think all of these cases can be subsumed under "The Problem of Non-Omniscience."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an interesting question. Conspiratorial thinking whether it is government organizations or pervasive forms of evil is something I've bumped into repeatedly. Clearly, one gets a sense some form of defective reason pervades in the mind of the person recounting how racism is found everywhere.

Before we begin, it is necessary to understand that reason is both an occurrence and a [disposition (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dispositions/), and with the use of fallacy, we have both a non-technical sense and technical sense that are themselves referring either to a disposition or occurrence. Technically, a fallacy is often taxonomized as a very limited linguistic construction. Perhaps a few premises which arrive at an erroneous conclusion either through a violation of validity or soundness. This would be occurrent fallacy because it is a very limited occurrence of reason (measured by length and structure of utterance) and would be understood as existing in distinction to dispositional fallacy which is a general bias in reason towards specious conclusion. It's therefore important to understand that taxonomies of fallacy are of the first sort.

When someone has grand explanations of the world that revolve around a repeated conclusion (he is racist because... she is racist because... the government is racist because... history is racist because...), what might appear to be an occurrent fallacy is probably more likely dispositional fallacy, the sort that taxonomies don't apply to because of their complexity. The [principle of compositionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_compositionality) asserts that dispositional fallacy is composed of a long sequence of occurrent fallacies. Thus, it might be possible to categorize the "Devil I Know" such as a flavor of hasty generalization, let's say conspiratorial hasty generalization, which might not be canonical nomenclature, but an accurate description of an instance of poor reason, but it might also behoove us to think that when it comes to reason, there are four classes of more and more pervasive and flawed reasoning moving towards a more applicable of characterizing a worldview rather than a syllogism:

- [Cognitive biases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_bias) and [fallacies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy)
- [Cognitive distortions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_distortion) and [irrational reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrationality)
- [Apophenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophenia) and [conspiratorial narratives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conspiracy_theory)
- [Paranoia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paranoia) and [delusional narratives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delusion)

Everyone is predisposed to the first class because these are pervasive, but normal errors in thinking. This is the stuff Kahneman explores in this [*Thinking, Fast and Slow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinking,_Fast_and_Slow). It is a modern psychological argument for the philosophical position of [fallibilism (IEP)](https://iep.utm.edu/fallibil/). I have three books that catalog this sort of thinking: Hamblin's work, Bo Bennett's work which can be found online, and Damer's work *Attacking Faulty Reasoning*. Part of what makes a fallacy is the limited scope and the criteria by which the reasoning violates good informal reasoning. **Usually, one is dealing with several premises and a conclusion that violate acceptable, relevant, and good premises which are persuasive, but can be shown to be erroneous in some immediate way.**

**When talking about a social justice warrior who believes that racism inheres to everyone's motives, is the lens through which all institutions operate, and is the primary lens for viewing history, that seems to me to be too pervasive to be a fallacy in otherwise reasonable thinking.** I would suggest that it might fall into one of the three additional categories in terms of severity.

Extended complexes of reasoning might inhere to just fragmentary reasoning embedded into non-coalescing narrative, it might be broadly apophenic reasoning that forms a coherent narrative, or if it is extensive enough, it is accompanied with strong feelings of anxiety or clinical phobia that manifest not only with a narrative that is conspiratorial, but is also delusional. Some explanation is warranted.

Every makes mistakes in reasoning. We're not computers, and so when we use informal argumentation, we make errors in judgement. If we do that in a pattern, it becomes a bias. Cognitive biases, like fallacies, have been observed in the hundreds and WP has lists of both. Fundamental attribution bias is a fairly common mistake people make often confusing the attributing poorly properties to people (their personality) disregarding what circumstances might play a role in decisions because others' experiences aren't transparent to us.

But the moment one starts seeing the world through such a lens consistently becomes a distortion which is pervasive rather than a one-off experience. Beck's work with depression is a good example. Depressed people tend to see the world in a consistently distorted way, and depressed people tend to make the same errors in black and white thinking. Clinical narcissists and people who manifest a pattern of BPD often face adjustment issues that show consistent distortion. But for the most part people in these classes of behavior are rather reasonable in the narratives of their lives.

Some people who might get along quite well in the world, though, see grand patterns in their narratives that don't quite align with how the world thinks. A typical example is people who are intellectually, but not emotionally invested in paranormal, supernatural, and conspiratorial stories about life itself. Everyone is racist. QAnon is going to destroy the DC. A race of lizard extraterrestrials is running the world. A race war is imminent in the US. Fluoride in the water is toxic and a government plan. Jews are evil and have a space laser.

But the reasoning has to be judged within the context of a person's cultural worldview. If you're a Christian, then it's not so crazy to believe that God is real and Jesus will rise from the dead. But if you start making the claim your neighbor is God and has risen from the dead, they come for you, particularly if you buy guns and start threatening others.

In an extreme form recalcitrant to counter evidence, then you may be dealing with extreme neurological dysfunction, such as is the case with schizophrenia accompanied by auditory hallucinations, for instance. Unlike the three previous classes, people who are paranoid and delusional generally become a problem for others and social institutions deal with them. A few hundred years ago, maybe you were just called possessed and hanged or imprisoned. One hundred years ago, they might lobotomize you. Today, treatment is generally just characterized as illness and you might be medicated.

You ask:

> Question 1: Is there a common name for this fallacy, and if so, what is it?
> Question 2: How does one distinguish this fallacy from inferring to the best explanation (called "abduction" by some authors)?

These two questions are two aspects of the same greater issue. **What is the best way to describe this pervasive failure of reasoning and preoccupation with a particular theme?** I wouldn't consider a pervasive conspiratorial theme of a narrative a fallacy. Rather, by the principle of composition, grossly defective explanation is **an irrational construction of a story by distortions characterized by fallacy and inappropriate characterization which demonstrate an overarching problem with normativity driven by an emotional preoccupation like fear or hurt.**

For social justice warriors, it's usually hurt and vulnerability, for instance. A person who believes racism or "those people" is omnipresent and responsible for the evils in the world isn't just committing a fallacy, they are demonstrating pervasive irrationality driven by fear of others. That means **you can identify a host of biases, fallacies, and distortions in their thinking, and cannot boil it down to a simpler linguistic construct, such as ad hominem or an appeal to popularity.** Thus, the question is one of the scope of language used, and the pervasiveness of the theme in the worldview of the thinker.

Comment: It just dawned on me that it would be clearer to state that a fallacy is an occurrence of irrational reasoning, whereas "The Devil You Know", a pervasive and persistent irrational conclusion in explanation and narrative is a disposition. To be clearer on the last claim is to have some familiarity with the metaphysical notion of [dispositions (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dispositions/).

Comment: Great answer. I'd suggest adding your comment to the text of the answer because my biggest problem with the answer was that you never explained the difference between a fallacy and drawing irrational conclusions. I was able to infer what you meant, but an explicit description of the difference would improve the answer.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Fair enough. Let's see what we can wrangle into the pen.

Comment: As always, other criticism welcome.

Comment: This answer seems to go very off track, becoming more about arguing that a particular example is illogical. It come across like it is more about proving that a particular claimed "social justice warrior" belief is illogical rather than addressing the question asked. There is even a debate if that term even describes a legitimate concept, rather than being a nebulous pejorative. An example with so many complications that could generate disagreement is not a good example.

Comment: @josephh "Referring to someone in these, albeit pejorative, terms is identical to claiming that the person has an unreasonable and fallacious worldview." That's exactly the problem. Making a contentious claim like that does not belong in an Answer. Examples of fallacies should be obviously incorrect, not something that can and would be argued against by a significant portion of people. I was highly tempted to start refuting claims myself. That's no good for an example. It reads like a conservative wanting to shoehorn an attack on SJWs, despite it having nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @josephh I of course presume that this is not the intent. They weren't trying to push a point of view, but just considered it obvious, and thought it was something readers would agree with. But that is due to my principle of assuming good faith. The inclusion of that as their chosen main example seems bizarre. Though I would also argue that a pejorative is not equivalent to a claim, as a pejorative also implies an attempt to use an emotion-based argument as well.

Comment: @trlkly The term 'social justice warrior' indeed has a pejorative connotations. As a progressive social democrat, there is a fine line between well-reasoned liberalism and multiculturalism that takes into account identity and being an ideologue of identity politics. SJWs manifest behavior that fits [Hoffer's *True Believer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_True_Believer). It is indeed a caricature, but there are people whose approach to reason demonstrate an emotional and cartoon-like quality. I could have choose the term libertarian wing-nut from the other side of the spectrum...

Comment: for the same purpose to demonstrate that there are people who seem to reach a pervasively poorly-reasoned worldview that seems preoccupied with what might be called philosophical bogeymen. In the case of wing-nut, the ideology consists of blaming the government for everything. Poor roads? Bad government! Crime! Government! Wife left me! The government's fault! A caricature of nativism or of white-nationalism achieves the same substituting a preoccupation with foreigners or non-whites as the "Devil You Know". What's important is not the politics, but the rigidity of ideology.

Comment: What's important in the response is the idea that poor reason can occur in small way (appeal to popularity) or systemically, as in a rigid, obsessive [ideology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideology) which seems to target something or someone. This can be true of political movements (Leninism) as Hoffer demonstrates and as the term ideocracy denotes.

Comment: @josephh And in regards to your interpretation, emotion-based reason and argumentation is the point of the response. When someone is preoccupied with racists, foreigners, non-whites, Jews, the government, Muslims, libtards, TERFs, political oppressors, fascists, whatever, and the worldview is built around a fear or anxiety of this "systemic bad agency", this is no longer the territory of a single act of fallacy, but is pervasive and emotional preoccupation that demonstrates a sustained effort to reason from conclusion to premises.

Comment: @JD Your personal political beliefs have nothing to do with actually answering the question asked. That's the point. This is not the place for you to be arguing that a group you politically oppose are being illogical. I get that you believe this, but not every reader will, and thus that makes for a bad example. You are instead inviting political argument, inviting people to tell you why they believe your logic is incorrect. Heck, your response to me is political argument.

Comment: @JD I’m going to stop at the part where you tell me that you’re a _social progressive democrat_. I really did not ask about your political persuasion nor do I understand why you are pointing this out. You seem to have gone off on another tangent, and the rest of your diatribe is probably similar. But Thanks.

Comment: @trlkly Thanks for taking the time to expand on your earlier comment and apologies for not understanding the full context of that comment. In a nutshell, you make excellent points and nothing you state can I disagree with. The answer above is about 60% answer and the rest total irrelevance. The answerer speaks to the question with germane points initially, and the rest is almost “venting”? I don’t know. Again thanks.

Comment: @trlkly Well, I'll be certain to make a note of your thoughts. They're important to me.

Comment: @josephh Yes. You correctly called out the venting. Thanks for applying your incisive wit to provide me analysis. I consider it some of the most intelligent feedback I've gotten to date.

Comment: @JD You are quite welcome. cheers.

Comment: @josephh hahaha

Comment: @JD Sorry if I caused you to ruminate on whether or not I realize you were being sarcastic, and whether or not you should reply to clarify. I knew eventually you would. Ego just couldn't take the risk? :) Cheers. (BTW don't take things so seriously...I was having a little fun here). Bye.

Comment: @josephh Who says I take anything at all seriously? I'm an Camusian absurdist with neurotic-level epistemic humility and regularly engage in Pastafarian rhetoric to raise awareness of Poe's law. My hypergraphia probably lies outside of your experience, and I bear you no ill will, particularly if you delight in whimsical self-debasement. ; ) Now go away.

Comment: @JD That's was actually funny! Cheers. PS I'll go away now too. :)

Comment: Wow. I was thinking this was a great answer, but maybe I don't understand all these issues well enough. My mother used to say, "*Discretion is the better part of valor*" so I'll bravely turn my tail and run.

Answer (score 10):

> There is no way a comedian known for playing the piano with his male organ became president of Ukraine without some hidden influence; therefore, the CIA installed him in the presidency.

I believe this is an argument from incredulity.

Argument from incredulity
https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/logicalfallacies/Argument-from-Incredulity

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_incredulity

Comment: +1 This hits the nail in the head.

Answer (score 2):

This type of reasoning looks to me like it is primarily based on statistically inadequate application of [*post hoc* testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_analysis).  In this case the speaker cherry-picks a rare/unusual set of circumstances *post hoc* after seeing the outcome and then conducts a naive version of a *post hoc* test.  In this test the speaker uses the *a priori* fact that *this specific* unusual circumstance would rarely lead to the outcome under normal processes to conclude that the occurrence of the outcome requires some special explanation involving departure from the normal process.  This type of reasoning is shown below.

The problem with this approach is that it does not condition on the selection of the *post hoc* testing procedure itself, which cherry-picked the unusual circumstance after seeing the outcome.  This method of inference is regarded as fallacious in statistical theory and it is well known to have extremely strong confirmatory bias (i.e., it often leads to confirmation of the asserted hypothesis, even if that hypothesis is false).  As to the particular selection of the CIA in this case as the alleged intervenor, this part is perfectly reasonable if you know anything at all about CIA activities in the Ukraine over the past decade or two.

---

**Unusual circumstance (X):** Person X is a comedian who played the piano with his genitals.

**Usual process (A):** A presidential election with no hidden intervention by a clandestine agency (e.g., the CIA).

**Unusual process (~A):** Hidden intervention in the election by a clandestine agency (e.g., the CIA).

**Outcome (Y):** Person X becomes President of a country.

**Naive post hoc test:** Measured *a priori* (i.e., without conditioning on the *post hoc* test procedure), the probability P(Y|X & A) is low but the probability P(Y|X & ~A) is less low.  Since X and Y are observed to be true, we infer ~A with high probability.

---

Comment: I think that all reasoning is post hoc, but maybe that's just my bias.